# Composer Update

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

***I am updating the Whole Question again today (14 September 2015)***

I am using Windows 8. I am working with Symfony php framework. I tried to update composer with this command 
**php D:\php\php\composer.phar update** . Then I got following error message.

```
    Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.18 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.
0.18 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.17 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.
0.17 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no mat
ching package found.
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v2.3.32
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.32
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.31
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.30
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.29
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.28
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.27
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.26
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.25
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.24
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.23
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.22
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.21
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.20
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.19
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.18
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.17
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.16
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.15
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.14
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.13
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.12
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.11
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.9
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.5
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.3
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 0.11.* -> satisfiabl
e by friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle[0.11.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v2.3.1
    - friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle 0.11.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle >=2.
0,<2.3-dev -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v
2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21,
v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2
.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9,
v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7
, v2.2.8, v2.2.9].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.0|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.1|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.10|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.11|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.2|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.3|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.4|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.5|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.6|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.7|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.8|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.2.9|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.0|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.1|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.10|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.11|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.12|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.13|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.2|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.3|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.4|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.5|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.6|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.7|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.8|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.1.9|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.10|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.12|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.13|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.14|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.15|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.16|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.19|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.20|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.21|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.22|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.23|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.24|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.25|don't install symfony/symfo
ny v2.3.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.9|don't install symfony/symfon
y v2.3.0
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony 2.3.* -> satisfiable by symfony/s
ymfony[v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.
3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.
3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.
3.32, v2.3.4, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further commo
n problems.
```

*composer.json*

```
     {
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.3.*",
        "doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.2.*",
        "twig/extensions": "1.0.*",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",
        "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/knp-menu-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
        "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "1.0.*@dev",
        "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.*",
        "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Could any one say what is the remedy of this error ?? Thanks

Comment: Could you post the version entries in your `composer.json` for doctrine and sylius?

Comment: Please post your `composer.json` and btw. you're not trying update composer, you're trying to update your dependencies.

Comment: You say that you are using Symfony, but you posted a composer.json from Laravel.

Comment: @AlexandruGuzinschi thanks for your comment. Actually I got that from Symfony Application. How do you know that  composer.json from Laravel ?? Thanks

Comment: @abuabu simply because in Symfony you have totally different `require` elements. Also, it pretty much looks like it's [Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/composer.json). Not to mention the post install, update and create commands are using `artisan`, which is Laravel's console. So yeah.. seems like it's definitely Laravel and not Symfony.

Comment: Thanks @tftd for your valuable reply. What can I do in this situation ?? thanks.

Comment: Try what @futureal has suggested.

Answer (score 6):

Try running the following command:

`php d:\php\php\composer.phar show -i`

This should print out a list of the packages currently installed on your system, along with their versions. Look for `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` to see what version it has.

If it is not listed, it is possible all you need to do is add this line to the `require` section of your `composer.json` file:

```
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.3",
```

And then re-run the update command. However, that seems unlikely, since Composer would usually retrieve that dependency automatically if there was no conflict.

The "~1.3" is coming from the `sylius/resource-bundle` which has that as a dependency. This means that it is looking for any stable 1.3.X version of the DoctrineBundle package (of which only 1.3.0 exists). This is also somewhat of an old version, as the current is 1.5.2.

There are some tricks you can do as far as fooling Composer into thinking that a package matches a certain version, though these are usually not a good idea as versioned dependencies generally exist for a reason.

Most likely more information is needed to discover exactly why this isn't working, as Composer will normally let you know what packages are conflicting, and it isn't here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with this dependancy:

```
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.11.*",
```

This dependency [appears to rely](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle#0.11.0) on an older version of [Symfony/framework-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/framework-bundle) which appears to rely on version v2.0.18 of
[Symfony/dependency-injection](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/dependency-injection). Strangely, there is a gap between v2.0.16 and v2.0.19 of that package and the versions you need are unavailable as the error suggests.

I found that I was able to get around this issue by bumping up the version number of your dependancy by 1:

```
"friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "0.12.*",
```

**However, you should make sure that your application still works with this change.**

The current version of [friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle) is 1.7, you should consider making changes to use that package if at all practical to avoid any weird conflicts like this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
sylius/resource-bundle dev-master requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.3
```

It's likely that the doctrine bundle uses an incompatible version of something you already use.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the list of requirements:

```
"jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
```

.e.g.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    […]
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "1.0.*@dev",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "*",
    "white-october/pagerfanta-bundle": "1.0.*@dev"
},
```

Comment: Thanks @Steve for reply. Now I am getting this error Fatal error: Class 'Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\SyliusResourceBundle' not found in D:\php\htdocs\my_project\app\AppKernel.php on line 25 Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handl ing the post-update-cmd event terminated with an exception –